# Expired authorization code

Tags: api, error, rest, php

I'm trying to use the REST API with OAuth2 in PHP. The problem is that I followed this tutorial : http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/interact-with-the-forcecom-rest-api-from-php
And when I try to run my this code I have this error :

```
Client error: `POST https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` 

response: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"expired authorization code"}
```

I suppose that I need to configure something on my Salesforces Connected App but after around 3h of googling I can't find where is my problem.

Do you have an idea?

thanks

Comment: Did you call /services/oauth2/authorize first? You need get your authorization token first, then call back to get your access token. Make sure you're getting a authorization token back.

Comment: Actually I'm using Laravel and https://github.com/omniphx/forrest. The first call is to /services/oauth2/authorize (where I log in) and my second call is to /services/oauth2/token and it's at this step that I have this error message.

Comment: @sfdcfox I still have this message after a new day of research

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I resolved my problem, I already used my authorization token previously in my code.

Comment: could you please explain more your answer? I am having same issue, once you authorize how cna you get the auth token?